# JavaFX include all modules dependencies inside a fat Jar and remove warning

Tags: maven, gradle, javafx, executable-jar, fatjar

I'm new at JavaFX and I'm trying to create a fat Jar of a simple program (password generator). With Maven (assembly plugin, shade or dependencies+jar) or Gradle I get it but a warning appears when I launch it from CLI

```
java -jar <jar_name>.jar
```

[prompt_jar image_info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyKVU.jpg)

> WARNING "Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed
> module @...'"

after all the program runs ok with mouse double click.

In the run phase (inside Eclipse) you can eliminate the warning by changing the Maven POM.xml (javafx-maven-plugin - 0.0.8)

```
<mainClass>org.openjfx.passwordGen.Main</mainClass> in <mainClass>passwordGen/org.openjfx.passwordGen.Main</mainClass>
more generally
<mainClass>"path_to_Main"</mainClass> in <mainClass>module_name/"path_to_Main"</mainClass>
```

but if you try in Maven (same previously plugins) you will get an error (ClassNotFoundException). 
In the manifest file the "Main-Class" will be passwordGen.org.openjfx.passwordGen.Main and it doesn't exist (seem it merge module_name with Main_path):

```
Manifest -> Main-Class: passwordGen.org.openjfx.passwordGen.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class passwordGen.org.openjfx.passwordGen.Main
```

The question is, how can I get a fat Jar with all the modules/dependencies (inside) required by JavaFX and eliminate the warning (with Maven, Gradle or Ant Task script)?
I have tried jlink method, it works but I don't really like the .bat file to launch the application. My goal is make a single file and simply double click it. There are also JavaFX JMODS file, it is possible use them to achieve the goal?

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

### INFO

In the class that extends Application (PasswordMain) I wrote:

```
System.out.println(Application.class.getModule().getName());
System.out.println(PasswordMain.class.getModule().getName());
```

and I get

> inside Eclipse : javafx.graphics passwordGen

> from CLI (with fat Jar): null null

Here what I get as fat Jar [inside fat jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHQpo.jpg)

### Script

Module-info.java

```
module passwordGen {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;

    
    opens org.openjfx.passwordGen to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.openjfx.passwordGen;
}
```

Maven assembly Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: filippo
Build-Jdk: 17.0.1
Main-Class: org.openjfx.passwordGen2.Main
```

Maven dependencies+jar Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.2.2
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17
Class-Path: lib/javafx-controls-17.0.1.jar lib/javafx-controls-17.0.1-wi
 n.jar lib/javafx-fxml-17.0.1.jar lib/javafx-fxml-17.0.1-win.jar lib/jav
 afx-graphics-17.0.1.jar lib/javafx-graphics-17.0.1-win.jar lib/javafx-b
 ase-17.0.1.jar lib/javafx-base-17.0.1-win.jar
Main-Class: org.openjfx.passwordGen.Main
```

Gradle Manifest with jar script

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": 'passwordB.Main'
    }

    from { (configurations.runtimeClasspath).collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } {
        exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA'
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    }
}
----------------------------------------
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: passwordB.Main
```

Comment: Shading the JavaFX modules into a user application jar is not a supported configuration, if you do that you will be warned about it.